# Multiple day event

Tags: calendar, resources

I'm using the resource pool for reservation purposes of cars. It works great when the reservation for the car is from 09 till 16.  But if a car is booked from monday 16 till wednesday 09, we can select this in the reservation form.  However on the agena view the reservation appears as it is for 3 full days.  When I take a look at the calendar/agenda view it looks like the reservation is for 3 full days however it is still possible to reserve te car on monday before 16.00 or wednesday after 09.00.  We use a function to check double bookings.  So the data of the item is correct but the view in the calendar view isn't.
Can anyone help with this issue?

Answer (score 2):

user19100,

I'm assuming that your resource pool is a customized calendar, or at least similar to a calendar, used to reserve resources for an amount of time. To combat the view of only the title in the graphic view, you can create a couple of columns and display those so it's easier to see exactly how long the resource is allocated for.

First create a column called "Time Span" as a calculated column with the formula:

```
=CONCATENATE(TEXT([Start Time], "h:mm"), " to ", TEXT([End Time], "h:mm"))
```

Then create a column called "Title and Span" also as a calculated column with the formula:

```
=CONCATENATE([Title], " ", [Time Span])
```

Then for the 'Calendar' view, modify the Month's display field as "Title and Span" and the Week's main display as "Title" and it's sub display as "Time Span". You should then be able to tell what time a resource is used on those days.